# Can't insert any data in a specific table into my database MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image]

In my case I have a problem with a workbench tool and also with MySQL console , the problem  is i can't insert a line into  table like the table showing above, and the other tables they work fine , i can't understand why some tables let me insert and others no, even if I grant the privilege to this database it doesn't work, can anyone tell me how please i will be grateful  ;)

> this is the decsribe for the table in question :

[image]

> also,this is the privileges :

[image]

Comment: When server ejects insertion it produces some error message. Show it.

Comment: Why does the first table image not look like the describe image?

Comment: @P.Salmon i have edit it

Comment: @Akina they don'y give me any error all work fine and successful , but the inserted data  in question was disappeared

Comment: Could you insert a row from the console and show your insert code and the result?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson ==> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec) => but i didn't find it in workbench

Comment: Can you see the inserted row using a select statement from the console window?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson  yes , but they don't take effect by my project and workbench tool also

Comment: So you can see the inserted row with a select statement from the console window? Then the row got inserted. It seems your problem is something other than failing to insert a row, right? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson i don't know because where i do search with workbench I don't see them , they appear just with the select query

Comment: I don't know what you mean by doing a search with workbench. What happens if you execute the same select statement that let you see the inserted row in the console window from workbench's sql editor window? Do you see the inserted row from the editor window?